# How to implement custom slider of my own?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I am new in iOS and I am trying to implement slider in my application. I have a button in the middle of my UIView and a button which will act like a horizontal slider and it should have three step (maximum, minimum, middle). It will show  two different views e.g. when it will be in middle it shows half portion of view1 and half portion of view2 and when it goes towards maximum value it will  show the full view of view1 and when it goes towards minimum it will show the full view of view2. I have tried a lot but could not find any suitable solution. Please give me some suggestion about slider and do tell me about how to implement this.

Comment: Code? Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use segmented control. Sounds to me, like that could solve the task.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement a method to layout your views and call them when the position of your button changes:

```
- (void)sliderPositionChanged{
    CGFloat position = button.center.x;
    view1.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,position,CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));
    view2.frame = CGRectMake(position,0,CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds)-position,CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));
}
```

One possibility to do the button movement would be using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on it.